# Why can not I get the area in this way?

Tags: geometry

I have this exercise:

Get the segment $AD$, if $AB = 20u, EH = 9u, BG = 12u$

[image]

My development was:

Let $A_t = $ Area of the parallelogram $ABCD$

$A_t = EH * AB = 180u^2$ ( since $EH$ is the altitude and $AB$ the base)

Also, $A_t = BG * AD$ ( since $GB$ is the altitude and $AD$ the base)

Therefore, $180u^2 = 12u * AD$

Then, $AD = 15u$, but my answer is wrong.

¿What is wrong in my development?

Comment: `A_t = EH∗AB = 180u` No, that should be $\,9u \cdot 20u = 180 \color{red}{u^2}\,$.

Comment: Yes, but that isn't the error. PD: Edited

Comment: `but my answer is wrong` Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong after your edits

Comment: Yes, but the correct answer must be: "The segment can not be determined"

Comment: I suspect that $ GB $ may not be height, but as far as I understand the height in a parallelogram is a segment perpendicular to both sides. So, I'm confused.

Comment: who says correct ans is undetermined?

Comment: It is perpendicular to both sides (both sides are parallel), don't get diverted by this diagram which is not portraying things well

Comment: The book McGraw Hill of Geometry, says that can't be determined

Comment: Is it a parallelogram by the way or you just assumed it?

Comment: Yeah, i'm thinking either there is something you missed in the question or something you assumed from the picture. Assuming what you said is true, your logic is correct

Comment: It's parallelogram. You can see the original statement in this photo in Spanish: https://i.imgur.com/j9Aa37h.jpg

Comment: I would say the key is wrong :P, better report it to the writer, he would be happy!

Comment: How do you know that this figure is a parallelogram?

Comment: The statement says that

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/j9Aa37h.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawing *resembles* a parallelogram, but it does not explicitly define neither $EH \perp AB$ nor $BG \perp BC$.

So, if your problem statement does not define $ABCD$ as a *parallelogram*, your use of the formula for the parallelogram's area is unjustified.

**EDIT** after a comment.

If the problem statement actually defined the figure as a parallelogram, then your solution is correct, IMO.

Comment: See the scan posted in the comments above, which verifies that $ABCD$ is assumed to be a parallelogram, and $EH,BG$ are heights thereof.

Comment: @Mattiu Your description of the problem, in the [version I saw](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2881846/2), did not contain that assumption, hence my answer. If you want to get correct answers, ask complete questions.